# Safe wallet creation check

Tags: wallets

I would like to understand. If someone can explain me, It will be appreciated.

According to the recommendations of Gnosis to check the creation of a SAFE wallet I've detected a difference with the creation of my SAFE wallet.
When I open etherscann and Contract I read: "Similar Match Source Code
Note: This contract matches the deployed ByteCode of the Source Code for Contract 0xdab5dc22350f9a6aff03cf3d9341aad0ba42....."

But  the recommendations say: "Check that the contract source code is verified."

Is it verified or not?

Why is it written this way?     Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> "Similar Match Source Code Note: This contract matches the deployed
> ByteCode of the Source Code for Contract
> 0xdab5dc22350f9a6aff03cf3d9341aad0ba42....."

it's say there are other contracts with the same code, which is as you'd expect

when the code is verified, you should see a green tick/check on the contract heading

[image: green tick]

and when you go to the contract tab, you should be able to see the source code

[image: some source code]